# Validate entered number to be integer or "half"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting input from the user and it needs to be either a whole number or some multiple of `0.5`.

For example, `7`, `23` and `5.5` are all valid but `3.1` and `2.7` are not.

In other words, if the user keys in `2.3`, there will be an alert telling them that they can only key in `2.5`.

How do I go about performing this validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they're entering strings, and floating point numbers are notoriously difficult to get right :-) I would suggest checking the string input itself, *before* conversion to a float.

If it contains the `.` character, make sure the last two characters are `.5`.

You may want to check other cases as well depending on what you want to allow. For example, `7.0` may be valid as may `2.50000000`.

But, for simplicity, I'd simply state that the input has to either be a whole number, or end with `.5`.

Comment: Oh, I don't know.  Seems like there really ought to be enough precision in a float to get 1 decimal place right.

Comment: Yes, but if the user _enters_ `2.4999999999999999`, would you want to complain about it or have it silently modified to `2.5`?

Comment: I'd call that close enough for government work.  But you're right; simply limiting to 0 or 5 for the last digit really ought to be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. http://jsbin.com/iyoneq/3

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button').on('click', function() {

 var val = Number($('input[type=text]').val()).toFixed(1); 
 if(val  % 0.5) {
   alert('This value should' + (parseInt(val) + 0.5));
 }

});
```

Comment: Ah, well I'm not sure I'd go with exact equality either. :)  Floats don't always respond well to equal signs.

Comment: Why not: `if (this.value % 0.5) /* value isn't multiple of 0.5 */`

Comment: You don't need `new` either, much better to create a primitive than an object, `Number(someInput.value)` will be more efficient. Note that it might return `NaN`, so you should deal with that.